# Azure Data Factory Dataset Structure Format

Tags: json, terraform, schema, azure-data-factory

I am creating a [Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.datafactory/factories/datasets?tabs=json#property-values) resource via Terraform. Here is the template from the official docs:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets",
  "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
  "name": "string",
  "properties": {
    "annotations": [ object ],
    "description": "string",
    "folder": {
      "name": "string"
    },
    "linkedServiceName": {
      "parameters": {},
      "referenceName": "string",
      "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
    },
    "parameters": {},
    "schema": {},
    "structure": {},
    "type": "string"
    // For remaining properties, see Dataset objects
  }
}
```

I am stuck on the proper format for `structure`. The first few entries are fine.

```
 "structure": [
                        {
                            "name": "id",
                            "type": "String"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "partitionKey",
                            "type": "String"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "createdDate",
                            "type": "Int64"
                        }
```

But then I need to translate a complex object and I am not sure how to go about it. The object looks something like:

```
"properties": {
    "title": "Blah",
    "tags": [
        "A tag",
        "Another tag"
    ],
    "description": [
        "So",
        "Many",
        "Words"
    ]
}
```

How do I parse this?

```
"name": "properties",
"type": "Object"
```

Will that suffice? Do I need to go into the nested keys? Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost: why do you try to deploy datasets from Terraform? Terraform is an infrastructure as code (IaC) software tool and is intended to deploy Infrastructure only (e.g. ADF instance, Azure SQL Server, endpoints, etc).
ADF's pipelines, datasets, Linked Services are typically application-type of objects and they should be deployed like that separately, after Infrastructure.
You can use [#adftools](https://sqlplayer.net/adftools) to deploy all ADF objects directly from your artefact or code.

Comment: We are using Terraform to deploy an ADF pipeline that is copying data from CosmosDB to Kusto/Azure Data Explorer. This section is setting up a temporary dataset that we use to copy that data from one place to another.